# How to stream files (or directories) in a Sequence in Kotlin?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, stream, sequence, coroutine

The idea is to build a spring-boot webapplication that returns a whole directory of files (mostly .csv and .pdf) upon URL-Request. The files are stored in a ceph-cluster and weigh a couple of gigabytes. Now to simply `return` a `ResponseEntity<Resource>` in the `@Controller` would only work with a single file:

```
@RequestMapping("/download")
fun downloadFile(): ResponseEntity<Resource> {

   val fileName = "data.csv"
   val fileType = "text/csv"
   val fileBody: Resource = ClassPathResource(fileName) // mocking the ceph connection

   return ResponseEntity.created(URI("/"))
      .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, fileType)
      .header(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, CacheControl.noCache().headerValue)
      .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=$fileName")
      .body(fileBody)
}
```

I researched that it is possible to stream the whole directory of files (and subdirectories). Kotlin also provides the Sequence type to compute the ByteStream sequentially.

Does anybody have a starting point on how to build a Sequence of InputBytes?
Do I also put the sequence in a Coroutine to accomplish an asynchronous Response?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your expected result regarding the network protocol/data? HTTP does not understand sending "directories of files". It works on stream of data. Stream could be a file, it could be a zip with files inside, etc. Do you control the client of this web service, so you can implement the same protocol on both sides or maybe it's just an internet browser?

Comment: @broot HTTP is necessary given that sFTP seems not be an option. Our client (frontend web application) is up until now unopinionated, as it will be our responsibility. So I guess I have to go the stream-of-data-way. Yet I am not sure how to start with this.

Comment: A common solution when we need to represent a tree of files with their metadata as a blob/stream of binary data is to use the zip format. It is possible to stream zip files in Java/Kotlin using `ZipOutputStream`.

Comment: Do you have experience in unzipping on the client side? Apparently it is mandatory not to ship a zip file to the user.